# How to check if a set field contains an specific value in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

This may be a really easy question but I've been looking for a while at django documentation and didn't find the answer.

My problem is that I want to check if, given a language, a user, who can speak multiple, speaks the given one.

My relevant classes:

```
class Language(models.Model):
    idiom = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)

class Profile(UserenaBaseProfile):
    spoken_languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language, blank = True)
```

Given: `query_set = Profile.objects.all()`

I've tried things like:

```
ls = Language.get(idiom="some language here")

query_set.filter(spoken_languages__idiom__contains=ls.idiom)
query_set.filter(spoken_languages__contains=ls)
```

or

```
ls = Language.objects.filter(idiom="some language")
query_set.filter(spoken__languages__in=ls)
```

Some more but without success, it seems it should be quite easy but still I cannot find the correct approach. Any idea would be indeed appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
profiles = Profile.objects.filter(spoken_languages__idiom="language here")
```

Note that calling `.filter()` on a queryset *does not change the queryset object*. Instead, it creates and returns a clone with the new filters applied. So if you want to filter an existing queryset, you should do:

```
query_set = query_set.filter(spoken_languages__idiom="language here")
```